# Basecamp API : How can I get the comments of the tasks of a project?

Tags: api, basecamp

The call projects/1/todos.json give me the comments_count field, but how can get the comments themselves ?

Answer (score 0):

We include the comments on the topic itself, so you'll want to make a request for a particular to-do, and you'll get the comments back in the response:

See https://github.com/basecamp/bcx-api/blob/master/sections/comments.md and https://github.com/basecamp/bcx-api/blob/master/sections/todos.md#get-to-do :)

Comment: i need all todos with comments is it possible with api ?